# Vb Linq "The value can not be null" using Group.FirstOrDefault

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have create this linq to get all rows of `tabRealisation` left join `tabPrevision` using `let` and `Group.FirstOrDefault`

```
Dim query1 =
(From r In tabRealisation.AsEnumerable
 Group Join p In tabPrevision.AsEnumerable
 On r.Field(Of Integer)("code_part") Equals p.Field(Of Integer)("code_part") 
 Into Group
 Let p = Group.FirstOrDefault
 Where r.Field(Of Integer)("code_part") = 276 
 Select an = r.Field(Of Integer)("Annee"),
        code_part = r.Field(Of Integer)("code_part"),
        Designation_part = r.Field(Of String)("Designation_part"),
        NbrR = r.Field(Of Integer?)("UniteVendu"),
        EncP = p.Field(Of Double?)("CAEncaissVentePrev"),
        RecP = p.Field(Of Double?)("MontantRecouvrementPrev")
        ).ToList
```

But if p doesn't contains any row i get the error :

> The value can not be null.
>   I have tried this :

```
    RecP = If(p.Field(Of Double?)("MontantRecouvrementPrev").Equals(DBNull.Value)
                              , 0, p.Field(Of Double?)("MontantRecouvrementPrev")),
```

but I get the same error message .
any help please

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` just prevents an exception being thrown in the case that there are no elements to return. You still have to check afterwards if the value it returns is `Nothing`

Answer (score 0):

Use the null conditional operator for when `p` is null; requires VB 14:

```
Select an = r.Field(Of Integer)("Annee"),
    code_part = r.Field(Of Integer)("code_part"),
    Designation_part = r.Field(Of String)("Designation_part"),
    NbrR = r.Field(Of Integer?)("UniteVendu"),
    EncP = p?.Field(Of Double?)("CAEncaissVentePrev"),
    RecP = p?.Field(Of Double?)("MontantRecouvrementPrev")
    ).ToList
```